# SetWindowPos changing X and Y positions

Tags: c#, winforms, pinvoke

I am loading the location of the windows last position from a config file (it is unnecessary to know why I am doing that and not using App Settings). The values being read in are correct and sent to the SetWindowPos P/Invoke function. However, on returning from SetWindowPos the values have changed.

Here is the code that gets the X Y positions and calls SetWindowPos

```
private void LoadSettings()
        {
            if (File.Exists(GetSettingsPath()))
            {
                string p = GetSettingsPath();
                FileStream fs = null;
                StreamReader sr = null;

                try
                {
                    fs = new FileStream(p, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
                    sr = new StreamReader(fs);

                    XPos = int.Parse(sr.ReadLine());
                    YPos = int.Parse(sr.ReadLine());
                    thisWidth = int.Parse(sr.ReadLine());
                    thisHeight = int.Parse(sr.ReadLine());


                    // Now throw the window to back and prevent it interacting.
                    SetWindowPos(Handle, HWND_BOTTOM, XPos, YPos, thisWidth, thisHeight, SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOREPOSITION | SWP_NOACTIVATE); // Set Form1 as BottomMost
                    sr.Close();
                    fs.Close();
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    if (sr != null) sr.Close();
                    if (fs != null) fs.Close();

                }
            }
            else
            {
                SaveDefaultSettings();
            }

        }
```

Here is the P/Invoke definition:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern bool SetWindowPos(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hWndInsertAfter, int X, int Y, int cx, int cy, uint uFlags);

        static readonly IntPtr HWND_BOTTOM = new IntPtr(1);
        const UInt32 SWP_NOSIZE = 0x0001;
        const UInt32 SWP_NOMOVE = 0x0002;
        const UInt32 SWP_NOACTIVATE = 0x0010;
        const UInt32 SWP_NOREPOSITION = 0x0200;

        private int XPos = 0;
        private int YPos = 0;
        private int thisWidth = 0;
        private int thisHeight = 0;
```

Obviously the XPos, YPos, thisWidth and thisHeight are not part of SetWindoPos but are here because that is were they are used.

So to the Questions:

1. Why is the X and Y Coordinates being changed by SetWindowsPos (The X value is < 1600 and the Y value is around 4)?
2. Can I stop this from happening?
3. Can I stop the window Flashing when being created and set to the BottomMost position?

Comment: Please read the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633545%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on SWP_NOMOVE and SWP_NOSIZE...

Comment: Surely it is "flashing" that's the explanation, the window was not moved but was *created* in that position.  A simple trick to not see it flash is to create it with an Opacity of 0 and set it to 0.99 after changing the Z-order.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that the window has a min size defined?